# How to test if MIDAS.DLL is loaded?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, datasnap

I use Datasnap on Delphi 2007. In a few specific machines when the user try to open the app, he gets the 'Error loading Midas.DLL' error and the app crashes.

I never could identify in what scenario this occurs, because i always distribute MIDAS.DLL with my apps and this file is always present in the same folder than the app EXE.

I know i could uses MidasLib to avoid that, but i can't do this because my app uses a cracking protection that crypto the EXE and ends up not being compatible with Midaslib embedded. So Midaslib is not an option for me.

So what i'm trying to do is to run a small test when the app to check if Midas.DLL is loaded BEFORE the app crashes, so i can be pro-active and register the DLL before the app crashes.

Here is what i tried :

```
function testMidas : boolean;
var c : tclientdataset;
begin
try 
c := tclientdataset.create(nil);
c.loadfromfile('c:\somefile.dat');
c.free;
result := true;
// everything fine
except
result := false;
// problem, do something to fix
end;
end;
```

This function works, it will fail if Midas.dll is not loaded and result false, so i  can do something to fix the problem. BUT i want to get the same result without having to call 'loadfromfile'. Only by creating the TClientDataset won't generate an exception.

Any ideas, please ?

Thankas !

Comment: `GetModuleHandle('midas.dll')` will tell you if the DLL is currently loaded in the calling process or not. BTW, when `LoadFromFile()` fails, you leak the `TClientDataSet`.

Comment: Lol that's right, i will .free on the except too :P

Comment: Better to use a `try..finally` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi determines where to load Midas.Dll from by examining a registry key.  Take a look at the source code of `CheckDBClient` in DSIntf.Pas which should be in your [Delphi\Source\VCL folder.

You'll see that this `CheckDBClient` routine generates the exception you are seeing, so there's really no need to check whether Midas.Dll is loaded, though you could use the method Remy suggests in a comment to check the value of the global var `DbClientHandle` which is initialized (or not) by `CheckDbClient`.

`CheckDBClient` is called via `CreateDbClientObject` in the call to `TCustomClientDataSet.CreateDSBase` in DBClient.Pas.

To fix the error, register Midas.Dll from a command prompt using Delphi's TRegSvr.Exe or Windows' RegSvr32.  Or you could register it yourself in your project's start-up code.  Delphi comes with the source code of TRegSvr (check your [delphi]\demos\activex folder) so you can see for yourself how it does the registration process.

Comment: Global variable `DbClientHandle` is not accessible outside unit `Datasnap.DSIntf.pas`

Answer (score -2):

Thanks everybody for the suggestions, but i ended up discovering that adjusting my code as below it works as i wanted :

```
function testMidas : boolean;
var c : tclientdataset;
begin
try 
c := tclientdataset.create(nil);
c.FieldDefs.Add('test', ftString, 20);
c.createdataset;
c.open;
c.free;
result := true;
// everything fine
except
c.free;
result := false;
// problem, do something to fix
end;
end;
```

BTW, i'm glad that when i post a Delphi question always there are answers, what indicates that Delphi is still alive and kicking despite a lot of people keep saying it's dead :)

Comment: What if the creation of c fails you get an AV in the exception bloc, put the creation line outside of the try - except bloc and opt to use try - finally where you free c on the finally bloc